# shiny + selectize.js: render custom item from local source

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I'm developing an application where the user will upload data and then select variables from that data to be plotted on a graph. I would like the variable's type to be displayed in the selector.

I'm working from the examples [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/013-selectize/ui.R) and [here (see "email contacts")](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). The shiny selectize example fetches the data via ajax, but I can't figure out how to adapt it for the data the user has uploaded, which is stored in my application as a `reactiveValues` object. I've also experimented with using the syntax from the selectize website example. All my efforts have resulted in the selector appearing with no data of any kind visible.

```
  # the code that creates the data I'm hoping to pass to the selector 
  stored_data$variable_selector <- data_frame(
    varlist = names(stored_data$data), 
    type = map_chr(names(stored_data$data), ~class(stored_data$data[[.x]]))
    ) %>% 
    purrr::transpose()

  # the code which currently renders an empty selector
  selectizeInput('variable', 'select a variable:', choices = '', options = list(
    valueField = 'varlist',
    labelField = 'type',
    searchField = 'varlist',
    options = stored_data$variable_types,
    create = FALSE,
    render = I("{
      option: function(item, escape) {
      return '<div>' +
           ' <em>' + escape(item.varlist) + '</em>' +
           ' (by ' + escape(item.type) + ')' +
    '</div>';
  }
}")))
```

Should I be making variable_types into a json object before handing it to the render in selectize? Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was testing it incorrectly: the following renders a selectizeInput with type information visible in the dropdown.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

iris_type <- data_frame(
  varlist = names(iris), 
  type = map_chr(names(iris), ~class(iris[[.x]]))
) %>% 
  purrr::transpose()

ui <- basicPage(


  # the code which currently renders an empty selector

    tagList(

    selectizeInput('variable', 'select a variable:', choices = '',
      options = list(
        valueField = 'varlist',
        labelField = 'varlist',
        searchField = c('varlist', 'type'),
        options = iris_type,
        create = FALSE,
        render = I(
          "{
            option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' +
               ' <em>' + escape(item.varlist) + '</em>' +
               ' (type: ' + escape(item.type) + ')' +
               '</div>';
               }
             }"
            )
          )
        ),
    textOutput("out")
    )


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText(input$variable)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```